# What is the best way to completely disable writing to an ostream?

Tags: c++, stream

This code runs on my computer in about 5.8 seconds.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    //ss.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);
    //ss.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    //ss.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit | std::ios_base::failbit);
    //ss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000*1000; ++i) {
        ss<<"i am groot!"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I remove the inner `for` loop it runs in about 0.06 seconds.

When I enable any of the commented out lines it runs in about 2.6 seconds.

Is there a better way to disable writing to a stream? I'd like the runtime to be closer to 0.06 seconds.

The use case is logging at various levels. At normal logging level, output sent to the verbose stream is ignored. Verbose logging is sometimes added to inner loops. We would like it to be as efficient as possible when verbose logging is disabled.

EDIT:

Edited to address comments.

This code illustrates the verbose logging use case.

```
/* initialization */
std::ostream verbose_log(std::cout.rdbuf);
if (log_level < kVerbose) {
    verbose_log.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);
}

/* do some work. log it's done. */
/*
this doesn't print anything if log level is less than verbose.
but it seems to do about 40% of the work anyway.
*/
verbose_log<<"some work done. result="<<result1<<std::endl;

/* do more work. log it's done */
/*
this obviously has the desired result.
however, the code is less elegant.
*/
if (log_level >= kVerbose) {
  std::cout<<"more work done. result="<<result2<<std::endl;
}
```

I would like to have the following things:

1. disable the stream if `log_level` is less than verbose.
2. format the code without the `if` block.
3. get the same performance as with the `if` block.
4. use STL.

To rephrase the question, is there a way to get all three?

Comment: When logging is disabled simply don't even attempt to send anything to the logging stream?

Comment: Did you try some logging library like spdlog, Poco::logger or Boost.Log? One problem in the C++ world is that many people want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: wrap the for loop in an if statement to check if the stream is good?  That way you skip the loop is the stream is bad.

Comment: Your example might be over-simplified. If you uncomment one of the lines, your code disables the stream, then writes to the just-disabled stream (and *surprise, surprise* nothing is written). Your use case suggests conditionally disabling the stream. Could you add a simplified version of that condition to the example so we can see how it fits in?

Comment: Is logging level a runtime variable or a static variable ?